# Speed Up Characters replacement VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, replace, cell

I have this little code that replaces the letters from a table like this (find the left string and replace it with the right string):

[image]

However it takes a great amount of time to do all the replacements in the sheets I have (just 2). Nearly 10 seconds. Is there a way to speed this up pls? Many thanks for taking the time!!

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Integer
Dim rplcList As Integer
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim myArray As Variant
Dim ReplaceCount As Long

Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Create variable to point to your table
Set tbl = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("StringReplace")

'Create an Array out of the Table's Data
Set TempArray = tbl.DataBodyRange
myArray = Application.Transpose(TempArray)
  
'Designate Columns for Find/Replace data
fndList = 1
rplcList = 2

'Loop through each item in Array lists
For x = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 2)

'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook (skip sheet with table in it)
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sht.Name <> tbl.Parent.Name Then
            sht.Cells.Replace What:=myArray(fndList, x), Replacement:=myArray(rplcList, x), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
            
        End If
    Next sht
Next x
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: How many replacements? Don't know how much difference it makes but you could restrict operations to the usedrange rather than the whole sheet.

Comment: `If Not sht Is tbl.Parent Then` would be a more robust condition to use I think. Do try @SJR's suggestion to use `sht.UsedRange.Replace` instead of `sht.Cells.Replace`, should be pretty quick. If a replacement triggers a recalc, consider also toggling `Application.CalculationMode` between `xlCalculationManual` (/off) and `xlCalculationAutomatic`, and if the sheets have event handlers also toggle `Application.EnableEvents`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Replace Strings in Multiple Worksheets

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub replaceOddStrings()
    
    Const WorksheetName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const TableName As String = "StringReplace"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = wb.Worksheets(WorksheetName) _
        .ListObjects(TableName).DataBodyRange.Value
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> WorksheetName Then
            For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
                ws.UsedRange.Replace Data(i, 1), Data(i, 2), xlPart, , False, _
                    False, False, False
            Next i
        End If
    Next ws
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Strings replaced.", vbInformation, "Success"
 
End Sub
```